# Get labeled version from TFS/Git in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I'm trying to pull a tagged/labelled version of a Git repository from Visual Studio. I also have it connected to TFS, where the Git tag shows up correctly as a Label, but cannot figure out how can I get the specific version.

The closest reference I could get was a part of MSDN documentation titled [Download labeled versions of files to your workspace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181439.aspx#get_labeled_files) - but Source Control Explorer isn't available with Git workspaces.

Is this possible to be done from within Visual Studio, or do I need to use Git command line and then open the solution in VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding on git works... 
Because Git is decentralised, and that you already have cloned the repository, you must have the tags and the commit corresponding to the tag.

Then in the history, find the tag and check out the tag...

Comment: Right - I was confused by the terminology, as in Subversion the tags acted as read-only branches, so I thought it's a similar concept over here